# Access $index from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to access the index of a ng-repeat?

I have the following code:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" href="#/tab/friend/$index">
foo
</ion-item>
```

then I click a item from the list I get to: `http://localhost:8100/#/tab/friend/$index`

But I want to get to e.g. `http://localhost:8100/#/tab/friend/12`

what did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular variables are only recognized automatically within `ng-` attributes.  To use those variables within regular html attributes, you must use double braces:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" href="#/tab/friend/{{$index}}">
foo
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have placed `$index` in the string and there is no way for angular to know that it's an expression. To make angular evaluate it, you need to use it as an expression e.g. `{{ $index }}`. Modify your `href` as

```
href="#/tab/friend/{{$index}}"
```